# how to fix InteractiveViewer and scrollviews competing for gestures

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, gesture

I have a vertical `scrollView` then a horizontal `pageView` containing images wrapped inside `InteractiveViewer`.

but it's quite a mess when I try zooming-in with the InteractiveViewer. all those scrollviews are competing for the gestures and I was wonding an easier way to get that fixed.

**Edit: So the problem seem to be with onScale gesture(GestureDetector()) or 2 pointer gestures**

I have something like

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
   const SliverToBoxAdapter(
         child: Container(
           width: double.infinity,
           height: 400,
           child: PageView(
             ...
             InteractiveViewer()
             ...
        )
      )
    ),
 ]
)
```

Comment: Well, current snippet should raise overflow ? are you wrapping PageView with any sized widget? are you targeting for web

Comment: No, I am only testing that on Android(12). You can wrap that pageView inside a Container/SizedWidget with defined dimensions. the issue I have is with gestures registering/prioritization. "pinch to zoom" doesn't seem to be priority even though its at the bottom of the widget tree. @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 1):

you can disable physic from relevant widget when user start to use interactive, maybe add some condition based on scale, finger, etc.

```
  ScrollPhysics _pagePhysics = const PageScrollPhysics();
  ScrollPhysics _customScrollViewPhysics = const ScrollPhysics();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          // assign physic for scroll ------------------------
          physics: _customScrollViewPhysics,
          slivers: [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 400,
                child: PageView(
                  // assign physic for page view --------------------
                  physics: _pagePhysics,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    InteractiveViewer(
                      onInteractionStart: (details) {
                        /// you can add some condition like this
                        //if use 2 finger
                        //if(details.pointerCount == 2){}

                        // then disable physic
                        setState(() {
                          _pagePhysics = const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
                          _customScrollViewPhysics =
                              const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
                        });
                        
                      },
                      onInteractionUpdate: (details) {
                        //condition based on scale
                        if (details.scale == 1.2) {}
                      },
                      onInteractionEnd: (details) {
                        // after interaction revert it
                        setState(() {
                          _pagePhysics = const PageScrollPhysics();
                          _customScrollViewPhysics = const ScrollPhysics();
                        });
                        
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        child: const Text("Lorem Ipsum"),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and if `interactiveviewer` leave no space for pageview or customScroll its always nice to add some button so you user dont stuck on `InteractiveViewer`.
you should make your ui like this :

[image]

Comment: This won't do, this is assuming it registered the 2 pointers already in `//if(details.pointerCount == 2){}` however it's not atleast before a couple tries

Comment: Changing the `physics` of the `ScrollView` is working well if we are able to detect if two fingers are touching the screen. Detecting two touches is easy like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72421013/3586084).